# Clarification about the flux through a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm sure that this won't be a very smart question, however I really can't see the solution. Given a vector field $\xi :=f_1\mathbf i+f_2 \mathbf j+f_3 \mathbf k$ and an oriented surface $S\subset\Bbb R^3$, I know that in order to calculate the flux I have to resolve $\int_S(\xi\cdot\mathbf n)dS$ where $\mathbf n$ is the normal unit vector to $S$. This is equivalent to integrate over $S$ the differential form $(\xi\cdot\mathbf n)(n_1dy\wedge dz-n_2dx\wedge dz+n_3dx\wedge dy)$, clearly with $\mathbf n=(n_1\ n_2\ n_3)^t$.

Then, I also read that I can obtain the flux by integrating the form $f_1dy\wedge dz-f_2dx\wedge dz+f_3dx\wedge dy$ over the surface $S$; however I don't understand how come these two forms are equivalent, since generally  $(\xi\cdot\mathbf n)n_i\neq f_i$, right?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The proof is in the link I already gave you. No, the forms are not equal on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes this doubt came from that link, I read that proof

Comment: Unless you have a specific point in the proof to ask about, I don't know what to say ....

Comment: Now that I read it better I think I resolved my doubt: the forms are only equal on $S$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you think about it, even though you get  formulas for $2$-forms on $\Bbb R^3$ (or at least on some open set containing $S$), $\mathbf n$ makes sense only on $S$ and, in principle, $\xi$ is only defined on $S$.

Comment: Finally that's clear, thank you very much